# Availability to meet vs availability to meeting?

Tags: differences, american-english, email

I'm writing a thank you email to thank a person for finding the time to meet with me. 
Which of the following two forms is correct, and why?

- I wanted to thank you again for your availability to meet me.
- I wanted to thank you again for your availability to meeting me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second version just seems ungrammatical, but neither sound good to me. I'd go for something like *"I wanted to thank you again for **being available** to meet me."* Or maybe *"**...making yourself available...**"*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I see, thanks for the insights. Is there a reason in particular why the don't sound good?

Comment: The entire tone seems [obsequious](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsequious) (which native Anglophones tend to avoid for fear of seeming insincere). But semantically, what you're trying to do is thank the person for *the **consideration he showed** in making himself available*. It just seems odd to single out the "intermediate" condition (his subsequent availability after showing that consideration). Personally, I'd get straight to the relevant "final" outcome, and say *"Thank you **for meeting me**"*.

Comment: Saying "I wanted to XYZ" instead of "XYZ" is wishy-washy.  (Of course, keep the "I wanted to" part if you mean that previously you wanted to thank them, but now you don't.)  Also,   “availability to meeting me” isn't standard English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Availability to meet, or availability for a meeting with me.

Though I'd go with your first choice: "Thanks for taking the time to meet with me". The other suggestions are, at best, excessively formal for most situations.

Answer (score 0):

When we say "I am committed to serving you" (to) is a proposition and the verb following proposition comes in ING form or we say  "I am looking forward to seeing you",pay attention when we say   (committed to) or (looking forward to ) "to" is attached to the verb as a proposition,this does not apply to availability.